# Discord.py Random errors from running bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

This question is mostly code because I have no clue what is happening and how to fix it...

I will also provide the main file. Thanks!

Code (looks something like this; Microsoft Lens is good, but not great) :

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import CommandNotFound
from discord_slash import SlashCommand
def mixedCase(*args) :
    total = []
    for string in args:
        a = map( ''. join, 
            itertools.product(*((c.upper(), c.lower( ))
                for c in string) ) )
        for x in list(a):
            total.append(x)
    return list(total)

client = commands.Bot(case_insensitive=True, command_prefix=mixedCase( "mc" ) )
slash = SlashCommand ( client, sync_commands=True, sync_on_cog_reload=True)

startTime = int(time.time( ))
client.main_startTime = startTime

class MyHelpCommand (commands.MinimalHelpCommand):
     async def send_pages(self):
         destination = self.get_destination( )
         e = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green( ), description='')
         for page in self.paginator. pages:
             e.description += page
             e.set_footer (text="Need help? Do 'mcsupport to join the support server!")

         await destination.send(embed=e)

client.help_command = MyHelpCommand( )
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    
    File "Bot.py", line 127, in <module> client. run( "TOKEN" )
    
    File "/home/quartz_i_warrior/.local/lib/python3.7/site-p ackages/discord/client.py", line 723, in run return future. result( )
    
    File "/home/quartz_i_warrior/.local/lib/python3.7/site-p ackages/discord/client.py", line 702, in runner await self. start( *args,** kwargs )
    
    File "/home/quartz_i_warrior/.local/lib/python3.7/site-p ackages/discord/client.py", line 666, in start await self. connect (reconnect=reconnect)
    
    File "/home/quartz_i_warrior/.local/lib/python3.7/site-p ackages/discord/client.py", line 566, in connect await self.ws. poll_event( )
    
    File "/home/quartz_i_warrior/.local/lib/python3.7/site-p ackages/discord/gateway.py", line 559, in poll_event await self. received_message(msg. data)
    
    File "/home/quartz_i_warrior/.local/lib/python3.7/site-p ackages/discord/gateway.py", line 509, in received_message func (data)
    
    File "/home/quartz_i_warrior/.local/lib/python3.7/site-p ackages/discord/state.py", line 490, in parse_message_crea te message = Message(channel=channel, data=data, state=self )
    
    File "/home/quartz_i_warrior/.local/lib/python3.7/site-p ackages/discord/message. py", line 584, in _init ref. resolved = self.__class__(channel=chan, data=resol ved, state=state)
    
    File "/home/quartz_i_warrior/.local/lib/python3.7/site-p ackages/discord/message.py", line 562, in _init self. stickers = [Sticker(data=data, state=state) for d ata in data. get( 'stickers', [])]
    
    File "/home/quartz_i_warrior/.local/lib/python3.7/site-p ackages/discord/message.py", line 562, in <listcomp> self. stickers = [Sticker(data=data, state=state) for d ata in data. get( 'stickers', [])]
    
    File "/home/quartz_i_warrior/.local/lib/python3.7/site-p ackages/discord/sticker.py", line 77, in _init_ self. pack_id = int(data['pack_id'])
    
    KeyError: 'pack_id'
```

Extracted using Microsoft Lens, I'll try to correct missed words.

Comment: Why can't you just cut and paste the code from your editor?  The code here is badly misformatted.

Comment: I'm not home rn so I had to access the vps from my phone; I'll update it when I get back.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the output and traceback I can see that the error comes from within the discord module. When sticker.py is used, and the class within it is initialized, the pack_id attribute is instantiated with int(data['pack_id']) which should return the value from the dictionary data with key 'pack_id'. It seems that it cannot find such an item. The keyerror suggests that the key 'pack_id' cannot be found in the dictionary data. Usually, data.get('pack_id', 'default value') is better used in order to avoid problems (if value doesn't exist, just replaced with a default value. I am not sure where the issue comes from here, but I don't believe its due to your code.

Comment: Hmm maybe the module needs an update, and my code doesn't seem to be the problem, thanks

Comment: Yes, I did have an update for discord.py, hopefully that was the problem. I was on discord.py 1.7.1 while the latest was 1.7.3.

Comment: Hopefully it will go smoothly from now on. :)